# Wrong bullet train oh-my-zsh theme render

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I have like an encoding error when the prompt is rendered.

I just installed the bullet-train theme for the oh-my-zsh plugin.

I installed the Powerline fonts as it is indicated in the bullet-train.zsh-theme file but though, my terminal doesn't seems to care.

It seems to be the right colors but there is "?" characters instead of the normal rendering.

Whereas it should be rendered like this: https://github.com/caiogondim/bullet-train-oh-my-zsh-theme

I have a MacBook Pro and I use iTerm2.

Comment: Please consider posting an answer instead of just a comment. That way someone looking for a solution for a similar problem can easily see that there is an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Install powerline font and pick one of those 
https://github.com/powerline/fonts

For iTerm 2 users, make sure you go into your settings and set both the regular font and the non-ascii font to powerline compatible fonts or the prompt separators and special characters will not display correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it by changing my settings for iTerm2:

simply change the font to a compatible one (powerline fonts)